# FaceDetectionListener does not update the rect for the current Face

Tags: android, listener, overlay, detection, face-detection

My problem is that in this function :

```
private FaceDetectionListener faceDetectionListener = new FaceDetectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        if(faces.length  > 0){
            Log.d("onFaceDetection", "Number of Faces:" + faces.length +"rect = "+ faces[0].rect.centerX() + " / " + faces[0].rect.centerX());
        }
        //TEST because the face has always the same coordinate except if the face exits the current rect
        //TODO
        //TEST
        // Update the view now!
        updateView(faces);
    }
};
```

the face has always the same rect even if I move the phone, expect if the face exits the current rect.

For example, I have a square drawn on my face to say that a face is detected, but I want it to move with my face. And this square moves only when my face exits the square since the rect of the face is always the same while I'm moving a little bit (but enough).

Thanks for your help.